# How to disable Lftp chmod permissions warning?

Tags: permissions, lftp

I use this script (launching lftp with some options) to mirror a local folder and a website.

```
#!/bin/bash    
HOST="myhost.com"
USER="user"
PASS="xxxxxx"
lftp -c "set ftp:list-options -a;
set cmd:fail-exit yes;
open ftp://$USER:$PASS@$HOST;
lcd /home/user/websites/A;
cd /;
mirror --reverse \
   --delete \
   --verbose;"
```

My problem is, on some websites, I have the error "**MFF and SITE CHMOD are not supported by this site**"

I believe it is not a very important error. It just says that  I have no right to set the permissions to the ones of my local files.

How can I disable this error message?

Comment: try `-p` option in your command

Answer (score -1):

Whenever you want to ignore error for output of a script just add || true at the end.

```
./shell/Script/to/run.sh ||true
```

if you want to make the exit code without any error, turn on pipefail.

Comment: This is only useful if you're comfortable suppressing all errors.

Comment: The question asks “How can I disable this *error **message?***” (emphasis added),  not “How can I make my script *ignore* the *error **status*** from the ```lftp``` command?”